# How to pin to TopLayoutGuide.Top xcode 7

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode7

This used to work in xcode 6, and is now grayed out in Xcode 7. Can someone explain why .Bottom is my only option now?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often want this for showing scrollviews below the navigation bar. Apple probably has a good reason to remove it and iOS 11 is getting rid of layout guides anyway, but for academic purposes you can still accomplish this.

First, start with a constraint between your view's top and the bottom of the top layout guide.

Second, get the object Id of your view from the Document section of the Identity Inspector (select your view in Interface Builder and type Alt-Cmd-3). In my case `c9Q-8h-rHu`. [image]

Third, open your storyboard as source code by Ctrl-clicking the file and choosing "Open as > Source Code" [image]

Now search for your object Id. In the results of that search look for a constraint where your view's top is constrained to some other object's bottom.

```
<constraint firstItem="c9Q-8h-rHu" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="pgx-wv-BwY" secondAttribute="top" id="OSD-K0-laA"/>
```

Change the second attribute to `top` and save. You can then Ctrl-click again on your file and choose to open as Interface Builder Storyboard.

Note that the constraint is changed to a "Align Top", but it's functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it? TopLayoutGuide.Top is just a top border of the parent view, isn't it? You can stick your constraint to the parent view instead of layout guide if you want your "overlay" view to cover the whole screen.